# How to change package name when installing React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-studio, package.json, package-name

[image]

The last time I encountered this error while trying to install react native on macos computer with terminal. What should I do?
The error I get is as written in the picture. Do I need to change the package name? why did it give this error? help please**

*I just started using android studio so I was afraid of doing something wrong. However, previous transactions were successful. I didn't expect to get this error at last*.

Comment: You didn't add the picure

Comment: yes sorry i added it

Comment: It looks like you created one project inside another one

Answer (score 0):

Because you have two `package.json` file in your project, `package.json` and another `myfirstRNapp/package.json` in a sub directory.

All information are on your terminal and it contains the path: [image]

All you have to do is delete the duplicated file in the sub directory `myfirstRNapp`. Don't delete the Main file !

Comment: Yes that is right. But I couldn't find the copied file.